# Optimizing joined SQL CTEs -- Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I really need help with the query below; with the CTEs and joins it takes 44+ seconds to execute, however, when I run the separate select statements each only takes 1 second. Why is it that it is taking 44 seconds when I join them?

```
WITH Z
     AS (SELECT GM,
                YQ,
                IG
         FROM   FN_qryFYQI(@pYQ1)),
     Y
     AS (SELECT GM,
                YQ,
                IG
         FROM   FN_qryFYQI(@pYQ2))
SELECT Z.GM,
       Z.IG AS IG1,
       Y.IG AS IG2
FROM   Y
       INNER JOIN Z
         ON Y.GM = Z.GM
```

Comment: Is `FN_qryFYQI(@pYQ2)` a function?  Can you post the definition of that?

Comment: And the execution plan please.

Comment: And the relevant table definitions, including any keys and/or indexes.

Comment: Have you tried without CTE ? Just simple join: `SELECT Z.GM, Z.IG AS IG1, Y.IG AS IG2  FROM FN_qryFYQI(@pYQ2) Y INNER JOIN FN_qryFYQI(@pYQ1) Z ON Y.GM = Z.GM `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  Z.GM
    ,   Z.IG AS IG1
    ,   Y.IG AS IG2
FROM FN_qryFYQI(@pYQ1) Y
JOIN (
    SELECT Z.GM, Z.IG
    FROM FN_qryFYQI(@pYQ2) Z
) Z ON Y.GM = Z.GM
```